# How can I retrieve an image from SQL Server using ASP.NET MVC with the Entity Framework?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2005, image

I have seen other questions about this, but I have not seen a complete solution for this.

I am using ASP.NET MVC with the [Entity Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADO.NET_Entity_Framework), and I have a SQL Server database using an image datatype.

#### View:

```
<% foreach (var v in (IEnumerable<MyNamespace.Models.MyObject>)ViewData.Model) { %>
    <span>
        <%= v.Name %>
    </span>
    <br />
    <span>
        <%= v.Description %>
    </span>
    <br />
    <!-- Display image here -->
<% } %>
```

#### Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index() {
    ViewData.Model = _db.MyObject.ToList();
    return View();
}
```

What do I need to do in my view and in my controller to insert my image while doing my best to stay with the principles of ASP.NET MVC?

---

#### What I have so far:

#### View:

```
<img src="<%= Url.Action( "ShowImage", "Controller", new { id = v.ID } ) %>" />
```

#### Controller:

```
public ActionResult ShowImage(int id) {

}
```

This is what I have so far, but I could be way off. It seems like there should be a much easier method to do this.

Comment: @The downvoter - this is a legitimate question, if you've got a problem with Rich, find another way to express it; personally I cry into my pillow at night.

Comment: @LFSR: Downvotes are fine, as long as we get a nice comprehensive answer to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Lazurus' answer, I have come up with the following solution. I like his approach, but for simplicity's sake, I am using this to get started and I think it is the best (for now) to help other's understand it.

Any better answers are welcome, as well as criticisms about this code since I know it is not very elegant at all.

```
public FileContentResult ShowImage(long ID) {
    return File( _db.Vehicles.First(m => m.ID == ID).Picture, MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg);
}
```

Comment: You don't need to initialise the Image to byte[0], just byte[] will do. You are then looping over the List when it would be better to use a query to just return a single element (just in case you get a second match). Also if v.Picture is a byte[] then just return that which would also end the loop and save needless iterations, i.e. return File(v.Picture, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg); rather than the Image = v.Picture;. Lastly, you'll notice that I returned a default image, something that's worth considering as otherwise you could end up with the missing image icon.

Comment: @Laz: byte[] Image = new byte[];  -- Array creation must have array size or array initializer

Comment: @Laz: If I knew how to do the query in EF, I totally would. I am just too new to figure it out on my own yet. That is where I could use help.

Comment: I think that should be much better now.

Answer (score 4):

The View looks fine, I just use `src="/Controller/GetImage?id=xxxxx"` which is effectively the same. The Controller action is a little different in that it's returning a FileContentResult thus. My image in the DB also stores the MIME type, the images are uploaded to the server so I just grab that at upload time.

```
    public FileContentResult GetImage(Guid ImageID)
    {
        Image image = (from i in myRepository.Images
                       where i.ImageID == ImageID
                       select i).SingleOrDefault();
        if (image == null)
        {

            return File(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Server.MapPath("/Content/Images/nophoto.png")), "image/png");
        }
        else
        {
            return File(image.ImageBlob, image.ImageMimeType);
        }
    }
```

Code to the Image class

```
[Table(Name="Images")]
public class Image
{
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true, AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert)]
    public Guid ImageID { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public bool OnDisk { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public string ImagePath { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public byte[] ImageBlob { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public string ImageMimeType { get; set; }
    [Column(AutoSync = AutoSync.Always, DbType = "rowversion NOT NULL", CanBeNull = false, IsDbGenerated = true, IsVersion = true)]
    public Binary ConcurrencyStamp { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What type is Image? Not the one from System.Drawing, correct?

Comment: Absolutely, it's a Linq to SQL class. I'll paste the code above.